The multi-task parallel mechanism of ”MAKE -j“ seems not to be working in a server environment
When I compile around 1700 files using make -j, it takes 13 minutes on an 8-core PC with 100% CPU load, whereas on a 56-core server, it takes 7 minutes but with only 10% CPU load.
Use MINGW64, PowerShell, CMD, all the same result.
About the make target:
all: -> all_build: -> $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET_BASENAME).elf -> $(BUILD_DIR)/ld.args -> $(OBJECTS) -> $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o -> ...
The $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o about 1700 files, occupy most of the time.
This is my makefile target and command section fragment：
#######################################
# build the application
#######################################
all: all-build
    @( \
        tTime=$$(($$(date +%s) - $(START_TIME))); \
        if [ $$tTime -lt 60 ]; then \
            echo "Build Finished (took $$(($$tTime))s)"; \
        else \
            echo "Build Finished (took $$(($$tTime / 60))m:$$(($$tTime % 60))s)"; \
        fi \
    )
    @echo ' '

all-build:
    $(MAKE) -j -f $(THIS_MAKEFILE) --no-print-directory $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET)

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET_BASENAME).elf: $(BUILD_DIR)/ld.args
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    @echo '[LD]: $@'
    $(CC) "@$(BUILD_DIR)/ld.args" -o $@
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '
ifneq (, $(DST_DIR))
ifneq (, $(DST_JSON))
    $(MAKE) -j -f $(THIS_MAKEFILE) --no-print-directory post-build-elf
endif
endif
    @echo '[SZ]: $@'
    $(SZ) --format=berkeley $@
    @echo ' '

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(CURDIR)/%.c $(BUILD_DIR)/cc.args
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    @echo '[CC]: $<'
    $(CC) "@$(BUILD_DIR)/cc.args" -MD -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(CURDIR)/%.s $(BUILD_DIR)/as.args
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    @echo '[AS]: $<'
    $(CC) "@$(BUILD_DIR)/as.args" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '

$(BUILD_DIR)/ld.args: $(THIS_MAKEFILE) $(LD_SRCS) $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, $(OBJECTS)) $(USER_LIBS) | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(file  > $(BUILD_DIR)/ld.args,$(subst $(SPACE),$(NEWLINE),$(addprefix -T , $(LD_SRCS))))
ifneq ($(CC_BIN), ccarm)
    $(file >> $(BUILD_DIR)/ld.args,$(subst $(SPACE),$(NEWLINE),-Wl,-Map,"$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET_BASENAME).map"))
endif
    $(file >> $(BUILD_DIR)/ld.args,$(subst $(SPACE),$(NEWLINE),$(LD_ARGS)))
    $(file >> $(BUILD_DIR)/ld.args,$(subst $(SPACE),$(NEWLINE),$(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, $(OBJECTS)) $(USER_LIBS)))
    $(file >> $(BUILD_DIR)/ld.args,$(subst $(SPACE),$(NEWLINE),$(LIBS)))
    @echo 'Finished building: $@'
    @echo ' '

$(BUILD_DIR):
    @mkdir -p $@

post-build-elf:
ifneq ($(CC_BIN), ccarm)
    $(dir $(CURDIR)/$(THIS_MAKEFILE))/PostBuild.bat \
    $(DST_DIR) $(DST_JSON) $(BUILD_DIR)/ $(TARGET_BASENAME) $(CC_PATH) $(PREFIX) $(user_postbuild) $(arg_postbuild)
else
    $(dir $(CURDIR)/$(THIS_MAKEFILE))/PostBuild.bat \
    $(DST_DIR) $(DST_JSON) $(BUILD_DIR)/ $(TARGET_BASENAME) $(CC_PATH_s32k3xx_gcc) $(PREFIX) $(user_postbuild) $(arg_postbuild)
endif
    @echo ' '

8-core PC cpu load

56-core server cpu load


https://accu.org/journals/overload/14/71/miller_2004/

Maybe you are I/O bound?

I think it's going to be hard to help you with a partial Makefile and no way to reproduce it.  Presumably you are doing make all so what is TARGET?  It does a recursive make which is problematic for parallelism see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel.html

@AllanWind  hello, I have added some explanations about the target, please take a look again.，thanks.

I have nothing to add.  My advise would be to rewrite the makefile to be non-recursive and invoke the top-level (i.e. the one on the command prompt) with -j instead of encoding parallelism in the makefile itself.

If you don't know you have a mkdir per c file.  I have used an order-only target with gnu make to just create whatever directories instead of doing that per c file.  Make sure to look at I/O utilization as noted earlier.

There's nothing that making it "non-recursive" will do for this makefile.  The "Recursive Makefiles Considered Harmful" paper is useful but it's not a blanket screed against ever invoking a sub-make.  It talks about not separating your build space into multiple "domains" by using sub-makes.  In this makefile, the only submake is used to ensure that the build runs with parallelism.  That paper is irrelevant to this makefile.

I'm actually shocked this even works.  By specifying -j with no argument you are telling make to run an "infinite" number of jobs in parallel.  That is, it will not place any limits: as many parallel jobs as you have it will run in parallel.  If you really have 1700 object files then I see no reason why it wouldn't try to start 1700 compilers in parallel, which will definitely not work well regardless of the number of CPUs you have.  If you switch to something like -j60 or similar do you see different behavior?

Apart from that and examining your disk IO performance as mentioned already I have no other suggestions, except that if you want a high-performance build server you should junk Windows and switch to a better OS for high-powered servers, such as GNU/Linux.  But presumably this is not possible for you.

hello，@AllanWind I removed all the mkdir command, but the CPU load during the compilation process is still around 10%.

hello，@MadScientist , i have tested -j100 ，it seems no different behavior.

@MadScientist There a recursive make -j of  $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET) which in turn does a recursive make -j build of post-build-elf.  It's not clear to me that this doesn't split the build space.  You may be right of course.

Does windows impose resource constraints on your program / user?   In linux that would be ulimit and cgroups.

The "build space" is defined by targets and prerequisites, not by amount of parallelism.  That paper is all about allowing one instance of make to see the complete dependency graph, rather than having sub-makes responsible for subsections of the dependency graph.  Parallelism has nothing to do with the structure of the dependency graph, it only tells make how many of the "nodes" in the graph can be built in parallel.  In any event, with "-j" (no argument) every make can build an infinite number of jobs, and infinity * 2 is still just infinity.

What does PostBuild.bat do?  Why do you have to run that with make -j if runs once after the binary is build? Does  make --debug=j  tell you anything interesting?

hello，@AllanWind The majority of the time is spent on generating the objs, while the time spent on other targets, such as elf and post-build, can be negligible. I have tested that simply building the elf target (make -j target.elf) does not trigger the post-build process, but the CPU load still remains at 10%.

hello, @AllanWind  It might indeed be an issue with the Windows system I'm using. I tested a very simple makefile that compiles all .c files in the current directory into .o files using make -j, but the CPU load is still at 10%.

hello, @MadScientist, The same information mentioned above has been synchronized to you. Thanks.

I might have found the reason. By using make for win32 install from Chocolatey (choco), I resolved the issue where the -j parameter couldn't handle more tasks simultaneously, which caused the CPU load to reach 100% at one point. Furthermore, -j caused problems due to too many concurrent tasks, necessitating a limitation, such as -j64, to prevent overload.

@MadScientist， FYI.

@AllanWind FYI.

Builds of GNU Make on Windows have multiple different ways of being created and I suppose some of them may not support parallel builds properly.  I don't really know much about Windows.  You don't say what version of GNU Make you were using before or how it was built or where it came from.  The error about "too many concurrent tasks" is exactly what I would have expected, if you use -j with no argument, as I said above.

You should write up that answer (what version didn't work and which did).
